# Time vector in curve fitting toolbox

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I want to use the curve fitting toolbox to model my day which consists of two vectors, time and measurement. Here is a screenshot of my data file (I will use time and DOWN only).
[image]

How do I feed the time vector as my x vector in the toolbox? It's currently datetime type vector and I can't find it in my list when I select my variables, what is the right format to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my excel sample (I reduced the amount of observations a little bit, but this won't affect the final outcome):

```
DATE        TIME        DOWN
---------   ----------  -----
1/27/2018   8:00:03 PM  5,375
1/27/2018   8:00:06 PM  5,375
1/27/2018   8:00:10 PM  5,375
1/27/2018   8:00:13 PM  5,375
1/27/2018   8:00:17 PM  5,375
1/27/2018   8:00:20 PM  4,855
1/27/2018   8:00:27 PM  4,855
1/27/2018   8:00:31 PM  4,855
1/27/2018   8:00:35 PM  4,855
1/27/2018   8:00:38 PM  4,855
```

I usually prefer to use the readtable function together with tweaked import options as follows:

```
opts = detectImportOptions('data.xlsx');
opts.VariableTypes = {'datetime' 'datetime' 'double'};
data = readtable('data.xlsx',opts);
```

The `data` variable will then be parsed as follows:

```
DATE (datetime)         TIME (datetime)         DOWN (double)
----------------------  ----------------------  ----------------
'27-Jan-2018 00:00:00'  '31-Dec-1899 20:00:03'  5,37500000000000
'27-Jan-2018 00:00:00'  '31-Dec-1899 20:00:06'  5,37500000000000
'27-Jan-2018 00:00:00'  '31-Dec-1899 20:00:10'  5,37500000000000
'27-Jan-2018 00:00:00'  '31-Dec-1899 20:00:13'  5,37500000000000
'27-Jan-2018 00:00:00'  '31-Dec-1899 20:00:17'  5,37500000000000
'27-Jan-2018 00:00:00'  '31-Dec-1899 20:00:20'  4,85500000000000
'27-Jan-2018 00:00:00'  '31-Dec-1899 20:00:27'  4,85500000000000
'27-Jan-2018 00:00:00'  '31-Dec-1899 20:00:31'  4,85500000000000
'27-Jan-2018 00:00:00'  '31-Dec-1899 20:00:35'  4,85500000000000
'27-Jan-2018 00:00:00'  '31-Dec-1899 20:00:38'  4,85500000000000
```

As you can see, when the time is not defined it is defaultized to `00:00:00`; the same goes for the date, which is defaultized to `31-Dec-1899`. Since the reference date is static and never changes, in my opinion the best thing to do is to merge the first two columns of your table in order to produce coherent `datenum` values to use as `X Data` (`datetime` variables cannot be used in the Curve Fitting Toolbox, you have to convert them to serial format):

```
[y,m,d] = ymd(data.DATE);
[h,mn,s] = hms(data.TIME);
x = datenum(y,m,d,h,mn,s)

x =
    737087.833368056
    737087.833402778
    737087.833449074
    737087.833483796
    737087.833530093
    737087.833564815
    737087.833645833
    737087.83369213
    737087.833738426
    737087.833773148
```

The values to be used as `Y Data` in the `cftool` can instead be extracted directly from the `data` column `DOWN`:

```
y = data.DOWN;
```